# Error code 191 on mobile devices when trying to post to feed

Tags: mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk, feed

I am trying to find out why my Facebook feed code only works on desktop but not on android and iOS. I am using the FB JS SDK. Here's the code in question:

```
<script>function postToFeed() {
            var obj = {
                method: 'feed',
                link: 'http://carscup.com/?vr=b518c73dd8915bc38da9d12fac0954a7',
                picture: 'http://carscup.com/pics_clubs/2_big.png',
                name: 'Join me in CarsCup! Together we can make HondaFan the best car club!',
                caption: 'Join your favourite car club, pass through various real life locations during your career, upgrade your car, collaborate with friends and compete in challenges against rival car clubs.'
            };

            var callback = function(response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "club_ajax.php?user_id=1753498414&fb_feed_posted"
                    }).done(function ( data ) {
                        $('div.share_bar').html(data);
                    });
                }
             }

            FB.ui(obj, callback);
        }</script>
```

I repeat, the code works fine on desktop (Firefox and Chrome), but doesn't work on mobile. I tried different browsers on my Android phone but makes no difference.

My app is not in sandbox mode, either.

Update:
I added "show_error: true" to the list of parameters and I receive this error:
"API Error Code:191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application."

So this points to possibly a URL issue. In the Facebook App settings I have the Site Url and Mobile Site Url set to the same thing: "http://carscup.com", which is intended because the site should work on mobile. This is also just a web site, not a canvas app. The app domain is also set correctly: "carscup.com"

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `show_error: true` to your dialog parameters, and see if you get a more detailed error explanation with that. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Comment: CBroe, thanks I have more info now.. It says:
Error code 191,
The specified URL is not owned by the application and
redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

Any obvious problems? I will Google these and see what I come up with...